# Scrapy FormRequest form_response

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm working on a Scrapy spider. I've found some examples online (including stack overflow) of how to handle sites which require a login. I'm running into a problem I've not seen mentioned anywhere else. When I run the included code, it will run the crawler, but when it tries to use the FormRequest.form_response method, it errors out with the following error:

```
2016-02-22 04:07:11 [schwab] DEBUG: init_request
2016-02-22 04:07:11 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-02-22 04:07:11 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-22 04:07:11 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.****.com> (referer: None)
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [schwab] DEBUG: logging in...
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [schwab] DEBUG: <200 https://www.****.com>
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [scrapy] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.****.com> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/pi/Projects/savingsScript/savingsScript/spiders/example.py", line 39, in login
    return scrapy.FormRequest.form_response(
AttributeError: type object 'FormRequest' has no attribute 'form_response'
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-22 04:07:12 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Another note, when I look inside the scrapy http lib for the function FormRequest.form_response, it appears to list an initial argument which precedes the 'response' argument I'm providing. Is this an issue of my arguments not matching the function signature of the method? Any insight would be appreciated.

The function signature in the lib appears to be:

```
def from_response(cls, response, formname=None, formid=None, formnumber=0, formdata=None,
                  clickdata=None, dont_click=False, formxpath=None, formcss=None, **kwargs):
```

The current state of the crawler code which produces this error is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders.init import InitSpider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class ExampleSpider(InitSpider):
    name = "****"
    allowed_domains = ["****.com"]
    login_page = 'https://www.****.com'
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.****.com/',
    )

    login_user = "****"
    login_pass = "****"

    rules = (
              Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'-\w+.html$'),
                   callback='parse_item', follow=True),
            )

    def parse(self,response):
      self.log('testing')
      pass

    def init_request(self):
      self.log('init_request')
      return Request(url=self.login_page, callback=self.login)

    def login(self, response):
      self.log('logging in...')
      self.log(response)
      return scrapy.FormRequest.form_response(
                                         response,
                                         formName='SignonForm',
                                         formdata={'SignonAccountNumber': self.login_user, 'SignonPassword': self.login_pass},
                                         callback=self.check_login_response
                                        )

    def check_login_response(self, response):
      self.log('check_login_response')
      if "<li class=\"logout\">" in response.body:
        self.log('signed in correctly')
        self.initialized()
      else:
        self.log('still not signed in...')

    def parse_item(self, response):
      console.log('parse_item')
      i['url'] = response.url
      console.log('response.url:' + response.url)
      return i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its from_response, not form_response! Tricksy piece of naming that.